# iterate over three vectors of different sizes . c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have three vectors . each one contains object Animal objects.
I want to iterate over them in this way-
from every vector I want to take the first element, than from every vector I want to take the second and go on.
If its not clearly, I want to create an iterator that does it.
There are two challenges-

1. the vectors are not of the same size.
2. I have a Boolean array that tells me which vector is available, i.e. it is possible for example- if I have vector a, vector b , vector c. so sometimes the iterator will iterate only over vector a and vector c , sometimes over b and c and so on.

I thought about it a lot and I cant find the right way to do it.

Comment: Are you iterating over all 3 at the same time or could you have 3 separate loops?

Comment: For 1. you need to figure out what you want to happen for vectors of different sizes. Only iterate up to the length of the shortest vector? Figure out some way of handling "element not here" and process all the elements of the longest vector?

Comment: So you want `a[0]`, `b[0]`, `c[0]`, `a[1]`, `b[1]`, `c[1]`, etc, skipping vectors when they run out?

Comment: What is the real high-level problem you are trying to solve?  Maybe looping and iteration as you've described it isn't even a good approach to the problem you are trying to solve with these `Animal` objects.

Comment: This may indeed be a XY problem: [https://xyproblem.info/](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.